# Form is not displaying ValidationError

Tags: django, python-3.x

It is not showing any validation error but reloading the empty form till the all form fields behavior validation.
views.py

```
def Leave_management(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        form = LeaveForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('leave_list')
        else:
            form = LeaveForm()
        return render(request, 'leave_management.html', {'form': form})

    if not request.user.is_superuser and not request.user.is_anonymous:
        form = LeaveForm(request.POST or None)
        form.fields['status'].disabled = True

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('leave_list')
        else:
            form = LeaveForm()
        return render(request, 'leave_management.html', {'form': form})
```

template

```
<hr><h1>Leave Application</h1><hr>

<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

{{form|crispy}}
<input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: That's logical, you create a **new** form.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah i know its creating new form but i cant understand because of which line this things happening

Comment: the funny thing is, it is even on two lines.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what are those line! sir! i cant able to catch it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is the fact that you create a **new** `LeaveForm`:

```
def Leave_management(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        form = LeaveForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('leave_list')
        else:
            form = LeaveForm()
        return render(request, 'leave_management.html', {'form': form})

    if not request.user.is_superuser and not request.user.is_anonymous:
        form = LeaveForm(request.POST or None)
        form.fields['status'].disabled = True

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('leave_list')
        else:
            form = LeaveForm()
        return render(request, 'leave_management.html', {'form': form})
```

So you created a new form that of course does not know *anything* about the values you have send through it.

But furthermore the `request.POST or None` pattern is not a good idea either: it will result in the fact that if you have a form that does not per se needs data, then the `POST` request can never get done properly, since then the form sees a `None`, and assumes that you construct the form for the first time.

The idea is to feed the `request.POST` to the form in case this is a post request, like:

```
def leave_management(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LeaveForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = LeaveForm()
    if not request.user.is_superuser and not request.user.is_anonymous:
        form.fields['status'].disabled = True
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('leave_list')
    else:
        return render(request, 'leave_management.html', {'form': form})
```

Furthermore we here *de*duplicate the codepaths. Whether the user is a super user has indeed some impact, but there is no reason to write the remainder of the procedure all in two separate codepaths. We can make an `if` statement that does the job, and then let the codepaths join again.

Furthemore we thus always construct *one* form (in the first `if` statement). Furthermore the name of `view` functions (like all functions) typically only use lowercase.